# Bun + stricjs application - how to add access logs / middleware functionality

Tags: javascript, bun

I've been trying to use Bun + stricjs for a very simple web backend. And I need to execute custom code before every request is processed without having to handle the paths myself

I tried registering a custom handler but when I request to `/view/file.html` the code for applying business rules is not executed.

```js
// .....
export default new Router({hostname: "0.0.0.0"})
  .use('GET', "/*", ctx => {
    console.log(`Applying super complex business rules`);
  })
  .get("/view/*", dir("./public"));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm the author of Stric.
When you go to `/view/index.html`. The handler of `/view/*` is chosen because it is prioritized at that subroute.

Also `next` is not a thing in Stric because it has no middleware.
Middleware is affecting performance.

If you want something to execute first you can use the guard concept.
See the docs here: https://stricjs.netlify.app/#/basic/routing/main?id=guarding-routes

Stric executes wildcards **only** if a handler for that specific path is not found.

Answer (score 0):

So the problem is the missing next().
In each middleware, you are required to give instructions on how to continue, you should register next()

So your final code should look like this:

```
export default new Router({hostname: "0.0.0.0"})
  .use('GET', "/*", async (ctx, next) => {
    console.log(`Applying super complex business rules`);
    await next(); // here's what i added
  })
  .get("/view/*", dir("./public"));
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer murphyy, unfortunately the solution you proposed didn't worked 
I'm still getting the result of the '/view/*' route.
Also, I'm getting the following error on my editor


This expression is not callable.
  Type 'Server' has no call signatures.ts(2349)